# QDirIterator: Reading directories and subdirectories

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having some trouble reading files recursively. Take a look:

```
QDir absoPath;
QString directory = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory();

QDirIterator it(directory, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while(it.hasNext()){
    absoPath = it.next();

    QFile totalFiles(absoPath.absolutePath() + "\\Total_imagens.txt");
    totalFiles.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    if(totalFiles.isOpen()){
        QTextStream in(&totalFiles);
        while(!in.atEnd()){
        qDebug() << in.readLine();
```

My objective here is to read a .txt file and count the lines in it. In each subdirectory, is supposed to have the same .txt file with the same name.  The problem is that the iterator reads the same .txt file more than one time.

Is there anything i could do? Change the names of the .txt files is the last thing i would want to.

Thanks for your patience and help!

Comment: Forgot to mention, each .txt file have different content.

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

```
QString absoPath;
    QString directory = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory();

QDirIterator it(directory,QDir::AllEntries |QDir::NoDotAndDotDot, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
absoPath = it.path();
while(it.hasNext()){

    QFile totalFiles(absoPath + "\\Total_imagens.txt");
    totalFiles.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    if(totalFiles.isOpen()){
        QTextStream in(&totalFiles);
        while(!in.atEnd()){
        qDebug() << in.readLine();
        totalFiles.close();

    }
}
    absoPath = it.next();
}
qDebug() << "Over";
return;
}
```

The only thing i needed to do was to get a QString to recieve the "it.next()" at the end. Thanks for the help...the flags helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the iterator goes throu . and .. also. That means each file is read 3 times.
Try using the constructor, where you can pass the dir-filter with the value QDir::NoDotAndDotDot

try changing

```
QDirIterator it(directory, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
```

by

```
QDirIterator it(directory, QDir::NoDotAndDotDot, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
```

Comment: Strangely, the iterator sets ".hasNext" to false and returns. Doesn't read nothing.

Comment: Try using `QDir::AllEntries | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot` as the filter.